# Drools 6.3.0.Final load rules dynamic

Tags: java, maven, drools

How can I load the `drl` file at runtime? I have read the Drools documentation, and I know that should use KieScanner scanner the rule `jar` . I have some questions:

1. When I update my `drl` file and make a new `jar`, how do I notify the project?

   When use the KieScanner, "ReleaseId" is hard-coded in project:

   ```
   KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
   ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId("org.acme", "myartifact", "1.0-SNAPSHOT");
   KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer( releaseId );
   // Start the KieScanner polling the Maven repository every 10 seconds
   kScanner.start( 10000L );
   ```
2. The KieScanner allows continuous monitoring of Maven repository to check whether a new release of a Kie project has been installed. If I run the project on the Linux server, do I have to install the Maven?

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.7 has java.nio.file.WatchService and several associated types. Using these to make some application aware of a change in the file system is just about as much work as setting up the KieScanner, and you don't need all that overhead.

Planning for a dynamic switch to a new rule base - certainly not a cut and dried matter - requires careful attention and raises several questions. Simply adding or replacing rules in an ongoing session isn't possible. So you create a new session, and what then? If you are lucky, your sessions have moments where all dynamic facts are gone and you can safely switch to a new session and redirect input and output. Finally, users have to be informed about the new rules...

Any automated mechanism isn't going to help much, and IMHO, it is preferable to have full control over all steps anyway.